# async I/O between three processes

Tags: unix, asynchronous, ipc

(I've faced quite a complex piece of software using asynchrounous messaging and am having a tricky bug, which I believe is relevant to async I/O, so I'd like to clarify some concepts).

There are three processes, A,B and C, and A sends control messages to B & C through a unix pipe. Now what happens is: process A sends a command to B, if network link is not up, B sends command to C('link up') and C later confirms to A that it's done, so B can change its state machine state.
Also at some moment process A sends 'link up' command to C. However state machine in B never changes, although when I debug with GDB step-by-step, it functions correctly (timings issue etc.?).

Also, another observation - I set breakpoints in both processes B and C, then execute A -- every time I start debug session, either B or C will be the first to receive the message, so there is no guarantee that B or C is always the first to get the message (I don't understand why).

Is it possible that asynchronous messages don't deliver in order, e.g. A first sends to B and then to C - can the B receive its message *first* and A gets its message second (first or second in terms of timeline)?

I understand there might be not enough information to make any assumptions, but what are the basic approaches to debug async I/O and situations similar to mine?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are both process B and C using the same pipe? Pipes are made to be one writer-one reader, so if two processes reads from the same pipe then if one of them reads data then it's not available to the other.